# Image Viewer application, Image processing with Display Data

Tags: c#, wpf, image, image-processing

I am working on Image Viewer application and planning to build in WPF. My Image size are usually larger than 3000x3500. After searching for week, I got sample code from MSDN. But it is written in ATL COM.

So I am planning to work and build the Image viewer as follows:
After reading the Image I will scale down to my viewer size, viwer is around 1000x1000. Lets call this Image Data as Display Data. Once displaying this data, I will work only  this Display data.  For all Image processing operation, I will use this display data and when user choose to save the image, I will apply all the operation to original Image data.

My question is, Is is ok to use Display data for showing and initial image processing operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course.  It will speed things up.  The only drawbacks are:

1. Having to replicate the operations on the real bitmap, and
2. Losing quality if the user zooms in while editing.

These are tradeoffs you'll have to weight against the better performance of the smaller bitmap.